# Make failing while trying to install SoX (spectrogram - libpng)

Tags: make

I'm trying to install SoX, and get through configure fine, but it fails on make with the following:

```
/bin/sh ../libtool --silent  --tag=CC  --silent --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
-I.  -DLADSPA_PATH="\"/var/tmp/sox/sox14/lib/ladspa\"" -DPKGLIBDIR="\"/var/tmp/sox
/sox14/lib/sox\""    -Wconversion    -g -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wall -W -Wmissing-
prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -pedantic -MT libsox_la-spectrogram.lo -MD -MP -MF 
.deps/libsox_la-spectrogram.Tpo -c -o libsox_la-spectrogram.lo `test -f 
'spectrogram.c' || echo './'`spectrogram.c
spectrogram.c: In function `stop':
spectrogram.c:593: warning: implicit declaration of function `png_set_rows'
spectrogram.c:594: warning: implicit declaration of function `png_write_png'
spectrogram.c:594: `PNG_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY' undeclared (first use in this function)
spectrogram.c:594: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
spectrogram.c:594: for each function it appears in.)
make[1]: *** [libsox_la-spectrogram.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/var/tmp/sox/sox-14.3.1/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I'm guessing this is more of a linker/pointer error than anything else because this is the beginning of spectrogram.c

```
#include "sox_i.h"
#include "fft4g.h"
#include "sgetopt.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <png.h>
```

png.h is included, which is where PNG_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY is supposed to come from. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is the code you're trying to compile publicly available? Are there any PNG-related `#define`s? What version of the libpng development files do you have?

Comment: Are you still experiencing this problem. If not, how did you fix it?

Comment: Sorry Gilles, I seem to have missed your message. @Tshepang - I fixed this by disabling png. If you're trying to install sox, I can't remember too well, but I think it was a configure option, have a look in INSTALL.

Answer (score 2):

If you're unable to get lib-png to work, and don't really want it anyway, you can specify it to try and install without png support (so no spectrograph) by doing:

```
./configure --without-png
```

That solved the problem for me. Leaving this here in case someone needs it!